# Three.js and useGLTF hook pathing problem

Tags: javascript, next.js, three.js

I'm working on a very basic project in next.js. I'm trying to learn three.js and I'v stumbled on a very simple, yet a problem that i can't solve.

On an attached screenshot i added my project structure. In Sculpture.jsx im trying to use useGLTF hook and it requires me to add the path to GLTF file.

Is there something wrong with the path that i'm pointing to or the problem is somewhere else?[image]

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  Suspense,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  OrbitControls,
  Preload,
  useGLTF,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import CanvasLoader from "../CanvasLoader";

const Sculpture = () => {
  const model = useGLTF("./sculpture/scene.gltf");

  return <div>Sculpture</div>;
};

export default Sculpture;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried several things, but nothing worked:
1) removing the dot in the path prefix. `./sculpture/scene.gltf` -> `/sculpture/scene.gltf`
2) downloading `Three` package
3) wrapping the Sculpture component with lazy function.
In the UI, I get now `can not find module `three``
In VS console, I get the error: input: '/sculpture/scene.gltf',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL.'